# What does this group (?<!^) mean in regex?

Tags: regex, expression

Newbe here, learnt some basics and came across this regular expression. Would be great if someone can help deconstruct it for me. Thank you in advance !

```
$source = "ExpandCamelCaseAPIDescriptorPHP5_3_4Version3_21Beta";
preg_replace('/(?<!^)([A-Z][a-z]|(?<=[a-z])[^a-z]|(?<=[A-Z])[0-9_])/', ' $1', $source);
// outputs:Expand Camel Case API Descriptor PHP 5_3_4 Version 3_21 Beta
```

Comment: There are different forms of regular expression. I'm guessing from the content of the string that this is PHP. If so, please add a PHP tag to your question (and you might as well remove the "expression" tag; it doesn't really add anything).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expression

```
(?<!^)
```

means "not preceded by start of input", or in other words "anywhere other than the start".

It's a *negative look behind*, which has the form `(?<!regex)` and is a zero-width assertion that the preceding input does not match *regex*. Replace the `!` with a `=` and you get a *positive* look behind. Remove the `<` from a look behind and you get look aheads.

Comment: Thanks Bohemian for the explanation.Just wondering how's that ends up replaced as space ($1)?

Comment: You can't. Look arounds are non-capturing. It doesn't count as a group at all - ie as far as groups are concerned it's like it us t there.